# Problem with fitting graphics card

Tags: graphics-card

I have recently purchased a new radeon hd5670 graphics card. The problem I have is that it is what I might call a double height card. So the end where you fix the card to the case is twice the size of the card it is replacing. But this means that it is blocked by the rear of the network card. The only way I can see it to cut that part of the fixture part out then I won't have a problem. But has anyone any suggestions what I could use? To be clear it is not the actual card it is the fixture part which is 90 degress to the card that is causing the problem. Unless someone knows of another solution - some kind of pci-e extender that I could use as I could easily

Comment: Pictures might be handy here.

Comment: You could get a new case.

Answer (score 1):

It is normally the extra-large cooling unit that doubles the height of the card. So do not cut it off !!

If you only have room for a normal-sized card, consider moving the card located directly beneath the video card to a lower slot if possible. However, if that isn't possible, or if you have a small form factor system that only has room for a single-slot video card, then you'll have to make sure your new video card is a single-slotter.

In other words, either you can fit it in as-is, or return it and buy another model that fits your computer. Electronics are too sensible to be sawed-off, and good video cards are costly.

Comment: This.  If it doesn't fit, you move stuff so it'll fit or you get another card.  DON'T try modifying the card...

Answer (score 0):

Check online to see if you can get a riser card. We've used those where I work to install full size video cards in a Dell 740